# Differentiate between RTP and RTCP packet multiplexed on same port

Tags: networking, rtp, wireless, tcp, libpcap

I am using `Tcpdump`to capture packets on my network interface. In `Wireshark` i can see that `RTP` and `RTCP` transactions are going on the same port. I am writing a dissector using `Libpcap` which will parse and save all the `RTP` and `RTCP` packets in different files.

### Problem

How can i distinguish which one is `RTP` packet and which is `RTCP` packet ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically RTP and RTCP [are using a different port](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3550#section-2.1). However, Duckduckgoing "RTP and RTCP on the same port" gives me [Multiplexing RTP and RTCP on a Single Port](http://www.ietf.org/proceedings/67/slides/avt-5.pdf), [RFC5761](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5761). [Section 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5761#section-4) discusses how to distinguish the two types of packets:

> When RTP and RTCP packets are multiplexed onto a single port, the
> **RTCP packet type** field occupies the same position in the packet as
> the combination of the **RTP marker** (M) bit and the **RTP payload** type
> (PT).
>
> […]
>
> To allow this multiplexing, future RTCP packet type assignments
> SHOULD be made after the current assignments in the range 209-223,
> then in the range 194-199, so that **only the RTP payload types
> in the range 64-95 are blocked**.

AFAIU, this means that when the two protocol are multiplexed in the same field, and if the RTP packet type is in 64-95, then the packet is not a RTP packet but a RTCP one.